# Can Spring use a simple String as form command object?

Tags: java, spring, binding, command-objects

I wish to use Spring's powerful binding tools (errors/validation/tag library/etc.) on a form that really only has one bindable value.  Rather than having an object containing a single String property ("name"), I'm trying to use a basic String as the command object, but I'm not sure how (or if) to get this to work with everything at the same top-level. Here's an example using the object (MyObject) with a nested string - this works fine.  I'd like to just use a string, but when I change MyObject to String, whatever is entered for this String is not reflected in the next page.  What am I doing wrong?

```
@Controller 
@SessionAttributes("command")
public class TestController {

private static final String[] WIZARD_PAGES = new String[] {
    "enterValue",
    "confirmValue"
};  

@RequestMapping(value = "doStuff.action", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String formBackingObject(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, final ModelMap modelMap) {
    MyObject entry = new MyObject();
    modelMap.put("command", entry);
    return WIZARD_PAGES[0];
}

@RequestMapping(value = "doStuff.action", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, final ModelMap modelMap,
        final @ModelAttribute("command") MyObject entry,
        final Errors errors, SessionStatus status,
        @RequestParam(value = "_page") Integer currentPage,
        @RequestParam(value = "_finish", required=false) Object finish,
        @RequestParam(value = "_cancel", required=false) Object cancel) {

    // submitting
    if (finish != null) {       
                    // do submit stuff here
        status.setComplete();
        return "redirect:/home.action";
    }

    // cancelling
    if (cancel != null) {
        status.setComplete();
        return "redirect:/home.action";                     
    }       

    // moving to next page
    int targetPage = WebUtils.getTargetPage(request, "_target", currentPage);
    if (targetPage >= currentPage) {    
        // validate current page here
        switch(currentPage) {
        case 0: // TODO: call validation
            if (!errors.hasErrors()) {
               // do some stuff to prepare the next page
            }
            break;                                      
        }
    }

    if (errors.hasErrors())
        return WIZARD_PAGES[currentPage];
    return WIZARD_PAGES[targetPage];
}
```

And enterValue.jsp:

```
<form:form commandName="command">
    <form:input path="name"/>
            <input type="submit" name="_target1" value="<spring:message code="COMMON.NEXT"/>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="_page" value="0" />
 </form:form>
```

And confirmValue.jsp:

```
<form:form commandName="command">
${name}
    <input type="submit" name="_finish" value="<spring:message code="COMMON.SUBMIT"/>" />
   <input type="hidden" name="_page" value="1" />
</form:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable. When you use MyObject, what Spring changes is the object's reference to the String, not the String itself.

Comment: I suspected it had something to do with String immutability, but why couldn't the reference to the String be changed by Spring the same way it does for an object property?  I guess really the why is unimportant if the conclusion is that it cannot be done.

Comment: See @Hung Tran's answer, that's exactly what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your case possibly caused by two things:

1) String is **an immutable object**. It means **a new reference value** will be returned whenever you assign a new String

2) A method parameter is **passed by value**. Because String is a reference type, then **the reference value** of a object reference **cannot changed**.

For example

```
public static void change(String text) { // (1) pass by value
   text = "Hello Word"; // (2) immutable
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  String str = "Hello";
  change(str);
  System.out.println(str); // Output: Hello
}
```

When we wrap a String object reference inside another object, then **the object reference** that is passed to the change method is **myObject**, **not the String reference anymore**. That's why using myObject can change the reference value of the String object reference.